# File.Copy access denied for .zip only

Tags: iis, permissions

I have website that copies files to external drives (removable media, network drives, etc).

The destination device is IIS5 and our testing is happening in IIS6. This error happens in both. It doesn't happen in IIS7 or Cassini. Note that my app pool in IIS7 is running as me, a super admin.

My piece of software copies files zipped or non-zipped files. I can have the website copy individual files and folders to my hearts content. However, I cannot copy .zip files.

The zip files are created on the machine in a temp directory. I am then using a File.Copy to put the created .zip file on the destination removable disk. I am also, in code, ensuring that the new zip file created is not read only (File.SetAttributes).

On IIS6 and IIS5, if I give the account "EVERYONE" full permissions, the task works as expected. The zip file gets copying with no errors. The problem is that removable media will be swapped out and we can't go into windows (on the hosted server) every time and give the account "EVERYONE" full permissions to the new drive.

Any ideas?